# Set the physicsNode.debugDraw = TRUE crash

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am studying the SpriteBuilder to make the example Peeved Penguins,but on the Joint step I set the `_physicsNode.debugDraw = TRUE`,it cash when I run my game,I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in obj-c, then you enable the debugDraw when you define the physicsWorld properties like this:

```
physicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
physicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0,0);
physicsWorld.debugDraw = NO;
physicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;
[self addChild:physicsWorld];
```

This is assuming that you have created a physics world